# PHP Curl request does not work outside of Postman environment - formdata containing array

Tags: php, curl, postman

Using the following code:

```
   $curl = curl_init();
```

`curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.sample.com/v2/clients?token=DMfJjzWLngIn0JBHA0gWcg",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"active_registration_id\"\r\n\r\n123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"language_id\"\r\n\r\n79\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"archived\"\r\n\r\n{{archived}}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"enabled\"\r\n\r\n{{enabled}}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\nSamplePassword\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password_confirmation\"\r\n\r\nSamplePassword\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[first_name]\"\r\n\r\nJustin\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[last_name]\"\r\n\r\nTrudeau\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[email]\"\r\n\r\nemail@sample.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[telephone_1]\"\r\n\r\n555-555-5555\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[date_of_birth]\"\r\n\r\n1943-10-10\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[gender]\"\r\n\r\nMale\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[referral_code]\"\r\n\r\nAmple Clinic 123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[status]\"\r\n\r\nRegistration Pending\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"For Additional Permitted Parameters:\"\r\n\r\nSee Registration Parameters\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[date_of_birth]\"\r\n\r\n1943-10-10\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[gender]\"\r\n\r\nMale\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[referral_code]\"\r\n\r\nAmple Clinic 123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"registration_attributes[status]\"\r\n\r\nRegistration Pending\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}</pre>`

I am getting the response {"registration_attributes":["Missing"]} This code will work in Postman, but not on the production server. Is there anything wrong with how I am creating the registration_attributes array?

Comment: There's a `http_build_query()` function that can be used instead of sending raw request

Comment: `content-type: multipart/form-data;` are you uploading a file through curl?

Comment: So I should be building one array containing main form data and the registration attributes array and the using the http_build_query() fuction on that before it is added to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS line? What do you supposed the discrepancy is between Postman and this request that was output?

Comment: You can also pass an array to the postfield. As for the discrepancy, I suspect you missed the last boundary. You can search for multipart/form-data in its raw form and how the boundary works

Comment: there is no file being uploaded, I've tried removing the <pre>content-type: multipart/form-data; </pre> but I still get the same result

Comment: @JeremyGiles Can you just assign a basic PHP array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` with the necessary key-value pairs and check the response?

Comment: Remove the headers, curl will choose the correct one for you. Ifthe api require certain content-type choose one, not both

Comment: I've tried removing each header separately, then both to get the same response. I've also tried using an array (similar to the answer below) in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and that didn't seem to work either.  It looks like the boundary was incorrect in the header, but when I adjust it I get the following error: <h2>Incomplete response received from application</h2>

Comment: As in the accepted answer, it looks like the mutipart header and string were incorrect but even when correct they were not accepted by the server. Using the http_build_query and the requested application/x-www-form-urlencoded was the answer. I'm still not sure why postman would have generated the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS string looks like it's incomplete, it's cut off, but that's anyway a shitty way to performa a multipart/form-data request in PHP, it's much easier to just let php/libcurl create the multipart/form-data request for you. wich in your case would look something like

```
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array (
        "active_registration_id" => 123,
        "language_id" => 79,
        "archived" => "{{archived}}",
        "enabled" => "{{enabled}}",
        "password" => "SamplePassword",
        "password_confirmation" => "SamplePassword",
        "registration_attributes" => array (
                "first_name" => "Justin",
                "last_name" => "Trudeau",
                "email" => "email@sample.com",
                "telephone_1" => "555-555-5555",
                "date_of_birth" => "1943-10-10",
                "gender" => "male",
                "referral_code" => "Ample Clinic 123",
                "Status" => "Registration Pending" 
        ),
        "For Additional Permitted Parameters:" => "See Registration Parameters", 
        // ...
) );
```

and get rid of both headers, for different reasons: `"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` - this header is lying, it's not x-www-form-urlencoded format, it's a completely incompatible "multipart/form-data" format. `"content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"` - curl will set this header automatically, and with a different (randomly generated) boundary, if you set the boundary manually, the server won't be able to parse it. (because the boundary specified in the headers will be wrong)

Comment: Ok, thanks. The documentation specifies that the header should be 
application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  As I mentioned in the comments above, removing the headers and changing to an array still returned the same error. I think it returns the {"registration_attributes":["Missing"]}  regardless of what is set for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS so I think its not even getting any form data because of the conflicting header requirements

Comment: @JeremyGiles oh, if you're actually supposed to use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, then your original CUROPT_POSTFIELDS array is still completely wrong (because that is a hardcoded multpart/form-data request, not an urlencoded request), to use the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format, use the `http_build_query` function with the array like i posted above, `curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array (
        "active_registration_id" => 123,...)));`  - and again, don't set the content-type header manually, curl will do it for you.